# How to calculate the median of a set by using the subsets?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

I have a set of numbers $\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$. Those elements being divided into several sets so that each set have $y$ elements (assume that it's possible to divide without remainder). I know the min, max and average of each set. So I can calculate the min, max, average of the original set. I also can know the median
of each subset. But how can I find out the median of original set? I'm not allowed to use the original set to calculate it. I need to use the subsets. Do I to use the median of each subset for that?  What equation should I use for that?

This question is similar to this one I guess: [Relationship between subset medians and the median](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1801836/relationship-between-subset-medians-and-the-median)
The difference is that in my case, the subsets are disjoint. Can it help here somehow?

Answer (score 1):

If you only know the min, max and average of each set, then in general, it is not possible to calculate the median of the original set. It's not even possible to calculate the median of the subsets. For example, take a look at the sets $$\{0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3\}$$ and $$\{0, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.9, 3\}.$$

They have the same min, max and average, but the median of the first set is $1.5$, the median of the second is $1.4$.

Comment: What is missing in order to calculate the median? Also, why "It's not even possible to calculate the median of the subsets"? You did find the median of the subsets

Comment: @vesii In general, there is no direct link between median and average. So, what is missing is... everything.

Comment: @vesii It is not possible to calculate the median of the subsets *just from knowing the min, max and average* of the subsets. In other words, if you know that $y=7$, and you know the average of a subset is $1.5$, the minimum of the set is $0$ and the maximum is $3$, you still cannot know what the median of that particular subset is.

Comment: Yes but I meant that I have the subsets and I can calculate the median of them (I just can't use this method to calculate the median of the original subset). Is there a link between disjoint subsets median and the orginal?

Comment: @vesii Well that's not in your original question. Your original question states, and I quote, "I know the min, max and average of each set". So can you please rewrite your question so it asks what you want to ask?

Comment: yes sorry, rewrote it.